# .Net MAUI Azure AD authentication returns null token

Tags: .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui

I have implemented the Azure AD authentication as shown in this article, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication), but it isn't working. Whenever I use the AzquireTokenInteractive call it returns null. I followed the steps in the article exactly.

Can anyone please advise what is missing or what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I removed the WithAuthority as I am logging into our company Azure AD only and no other tenants and I had to ensure that I pass through the scope correctly.